# Orika mapping from one object to another object

Tags: java, mapping, orika

I have a class that has 2 different objects under same class:

```
public class Customer {
    //Source Attr
    public Addr addr;

    //target
    public AddressDTO custAddr;

}

public class Addr {

    public String street_Name;
    public String home_Num;
    public String post_code;
}

public class AddressDTO {

    public String streetName;
    public String homeNum;
    public String postcode;
}
```

I am trying to map Addr -> AddressDTO object in Customer Object:

```
ClassMapBuilder<?,?> classMapper = factory.classMap(Customer.class, Customer.class).classMap.field(addr.street_Name, custAddr.streetName).byDefault().register();

Customer source = new Customer();
source.setName("tester");
Addr addr = new Addr("streetname","123","456");
source.setAddr(addr);

Customer target = mapper.map(source,Customer.class);
```

When I run this, i get this error:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.String is an unsupported source class for constructing instances of com.domain.AddressDTO

Comment: Show the constructors and mark if all fields have getters/setters.

Comment: Your code is missing a lot of things. Actually, it does not compile.
I guess you are not showing all your code.